# How add parametr -fvisibility=default to CMAKE?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qtwebkit

I need get hidden API WebCore from qtwebkit.

For example

```
    QWebPage *page = mainWidget->page();    
    QWebFrame *qtWebFrame = mainWidget->page()->mainFrame();
    QWebFramePrivate *qtWebFramePrivate = qtWebFrame->d;
    WebCore::Frame *frame = qtWebFramePrivate->frame;

    WebCore::DocumentWriter m_writer(frame);
    m_writer.setFrame(frame);
    m_writer.begin(url, false);
    m_writer.setDocumentWasLoadedAsPartOfNavigation();
    m_writer.setEncoding("utf-8", true);    
    m_writer.addData(html ,strlen(html) );
    m_writer.end();
```

How export this private WebCore ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the correct property on your target :

```
add_executable(MyTarget ...)

set_target_properties(MyTarget PROPERTIES CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET default)
```